# Separating between Hebrew and English strings

Tags: python, regex, hebrew

So I have this huge list of strings in Hebrew and English, and I want to extract from them only those in Hebrew, but couldn't find a regex example that works with Hebrew.

I have tried the stupid method of comparing every character:

```
import string
data = []
for s in slist:
    found = False
    for c in string.ascii_letters:
        if c in s:
            found = True
    if not found:
        data.append(s)
```

And it works, but it is of course very slow and my list is HUGE.
Instead of this, I tried comparing only the first letter of the string to `string.ascii_letters` which was much faster, but it only filters out those that start with an English letter, and leaves the "mixed" strings in there. I only want those that are "pure" Hebrew.

I'm sure this can be done much better... Help, anyone?

P.S: I prefer to do it within a python program, but a grep command that does the same would also help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check if a string contains any ASCII letters (ie. non-Hebrew) use:

```
re.search('[' + string.ascii_letters + ']', s)
```

If this returns true, your string is not pure Hebrew.

Answer (score 2):

This one should work:

```
import re
data = [s for s in slist if re.match('^[a-zA-Z ]+$', s)]
```

This will pick all the strings that consist of lowercase and uppercase English letters and spaces. If the strings are allowed to contain digits or punctuation marks, the allowed characters should be included into the regex.

Edit: Just noticed, it filters out the English-only strings, but you need it do do the other way round. You can try this instead:

```
data = [s for s in slist if not re.match('^.*[a-zA-Z].*$', s)]
```

This will discard any string that contains at least one English letter.

Comment: tried it as well, fails to find strings that are not entirely English

Comment: @OferSadan Yeah, I've updated the answer. This one should work.

Answer (score 2):

Python has extensive unicode support. It depends on what you're asking for. Is a hebrew word one that contains only hebrew characters and whitespace, or is it simply a word that contains no latin characters? Either way, you can do so directly. Just create the criteria set and test for membership.

Note that testing for membership in a set is much faster than iteration through string.ascii_letters.

Please note that I do not speak hebrew so I may have missed a letter or two of the alphabet.

```
def is_hebrew(word):
    hebrew = set("א‎ב‎ג‎ד‎ה‎ו‎ז‎ח‎ט‎י‎כ‎ך‎ל‎מ‎נ‎ס‎  ע‎פ‎צ‎ק‎ר‎ש‎ת‎ם‎ן‎ף‎ץ"+string.whitespace)
    for char in word:
        if char not in hebrew:
            return False
    return True

def contains_latin(word):
    return any(char in set("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz") for char in word.lower())
# a generator expression like this is a terser way of expressing the 
# above concept.

hebrew_words = [word for word in words if is_hebrew(word)]
non_latin words = [word for word in words if not contains_latin(word)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to create a dictionary of hebrew words:

```
hebrew_words = {...}
```

And then you iterate through the list of words and compare them against this dictionary ignoring case. This will work much faster than other approaches (O(n) where n is the length of your list of words).

The downside is that you need to get all or most of hebrew words somewhere. I think it's possible to find it on the web in csv or some other form. Parse it and put it into python dictionary.

However, it makes sense if you need to parse such lists of words very often and quite quickly. Another problem is that the dictionary may contain not all hebrew words which will not give a completely right answer.

Comment: This isn't useful at all, some of the strings are multiple words and some of them are gibberish but I still need them because they contain only Hebrew letters

Comment: @OferSadan Then, yes, it's better to use regex. But it will be slower.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> import re
>>> filter(lambda x: re.match(r'^[^\w]+$',x),s)
```